# Trying to determine if this sentence needs a comma; in my head it does, but I can't articulate why

Tags: commas

"His neck took to what had become apparent its characteristically unnatural bend."

In my head, this **needs** a comma after "apparent," but I'd like to know with certainty whether it is necessary and, if so, why?

Comment: I'm sorry,  but I think that sentence needs much more than a comma to set it right.

Comment: What are you trying to say? The only possible punctuation that  I can see going after "apparent" would be a colon.

Comment: Can you put it in the original language?  It looks like someone used a [bad] automated translator.

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "taking to that position" in your comment.  Do you mean that his neck was *in* that position?

Comment: Does the sentence mean "His neck assumed an unnatural bend which, it was becoming clear, was its characteristic position"?

Comment: Agree this needs more just than a comma. I would rephrase this to something like "His neck took to the unnatural bend that had become apparent to be characteristic for it".

Comment: Judging by the various comments and answers, it seems that no-one likes this sentence in its present form. Alias - Please can you say where this sentence came from. Did you write it? Is it from a book or other publication? Did you copy it perfectly? Is it a Google translation?  We need to know these things otherwise a lot of time is wasted.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is definitely wrong. It should read

> His neck took to what had become apparent *was* its characteristically unnatural bend.

And a comma anywhere in there would be wrong.

If you really want commas in there, you can do it like this:

> His neck took to what, as had become apparent, was its characteristically unnatural bend.

But that sounds even clunkier to me.

Comment: We weren't asked to rewrite the sentence - only the punctuation. By changing the wording, you aren't answering the original question, q.v.

Comment: @chasly: the OP's sentence is too broken to be fixed by a comma or two. And you don't seem to have understood my comment to your answer at all. Would you really correct "He showed me what I thought his passport" by adding a colon?

Comment: You could say, "He showed me what I expected: his passport", You could could say, "He showed me what I thought to be his passport." You could make all sorts of changes. In fact I have now voted to close this question because it shows no evidence of the source or the correctness of the transcription. Since I am voting to close, I will soon delete my answer for  reasons within the rules of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two different problems with this sentence that are leading in opposite directions.

On first reading, the sentence appears to consist of two clauses:

- His neck took to [something which] had become apparent
- [the thing it took to was] its characteristically unnatural bend

As [another answer says](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/539635/108983), these would most correctly be separated by a colon.

However, the intention seems to be that what had become apparent was not the bend itself, but *the fact that it was characteristic*. So we could try moving the "characteristic" into the first clause, to reunite it with "apparent":

- His neck took to [something which] had become apparently characteristic
- [the thing it took to was] an unnatural bend

But this is still unclear: is it "become ... characteristic" + "apparently" or "become" + "apparently characteristic"?

We would therefore be better moving "become" and "apparent" into a third, parenthetical clause:

- His neck took to something which ... was characteristic
- [the fact that it was characteristic] had become apparent
- [the thing it took to was] an unnatural bend

Re-constructing the sentence, we might say:

> His neck took to something which, it had become apparent, was characteristic: an unnatural bend.